# SSIS 2012 with mongodb 3.2

Tags: c#, mongodb, ssis

I'm trying to build some ETL package using SSIS to load data between MongoDB and MSSQL Server. According to this article Importing MongoDB Data Using SSIS 2012, I need to install MongoDB C# driver. I installed CSharpDriver-2.2.4. However, gacutil complains the DLL is not signed with strong names when i compiled the c# component script.

Pls point me to a copy of strongly signed driver or give me your suggestions
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to sign those dlls building them on your workstation.

You can download csharp driver project [here from github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver), then generate test-cert or use your own.

Security point behind that is - someone could give you signed ones by not trusted CA - so such cert have to manual imported and all `other` software could be trusted based on that `imported` certificate.

So sign yourself :-)

Any comments welcome!

Comment: Thanks profesor79. I am working on your suggestion and will let you know the result.